# Plotting Surface produce spikes in TIKZ but not in gnuplot, Gnuplot plotting problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I have 2 problems:

1) I am trying to do a surfaceplot in TIKZ but unfortunately TIKZ produces spikes that gnuplot is not producing.

2) if I try to use gnuplot inside of TIKZ, the only output is a empty 2d plots (see picture 2). Code provided in MWE.

Picture of Plots and equation provided below MWE.

MWE:

```
  \documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{width=7.5cm,compat=newest,
       }

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf,terminaloptions=color]
set grid nopolar
set style increment default
set isosamples 50, 50
set style data lines
set title '3D surface from a function' 
set xlabel 'QD' 
set xrange [ 500 : 200] noreverse nowriteback
set ylabel 'QD' 
set yrange [200 : 1500 ] noreverse nowriteback
set contour
set zlabel 'K'
set samples 100, 100
Kle(x,y,k)=((x*exp(k/y)*(x*y*exp(k/y)+(k-x)*exp(k/x)*y-x*k*exp(k/x)))/(y*(x*exp(k/y)-exp(k/x)*y)**2))
splot Kle(x,y,500)
\end{gnuplot}



\begin{tikzpicture}
[show background rectangle,tight background,
declare function={
kqd2(\qb,\qd,\koa) = {((\qb*e^(\koa/\qd)*(\qb*\qd*e^(\koa/\qd)+(\koa-\qb)*e^(\koa/\qb)*\qd-\qb*\koa*e^(\koa/\qb)))/(\qd*(\qb*e^(\koa/\qd)-e^(\koa/\qb)*\qd)^2))};
},
]
\begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth,
       height=\textwidth,
    title={nummer1}, 
    xlabel=$QB$, ylabel=$QD$, zlabel=$\frac{\partial k}{\partial QD}$,
    xtick={200, 300,400, 500},
        ytick={ 500,1000,1500},
             zlabel style={yshift=-0.25cm}, 
     xlabel style={yshift=0.25cm},
          ylabel style={yshift=.25cm},
%          zmin=0, zmax=1,
                   ztick={0,0.5,1},
          x dir=reverse,
          grid=major,
%           unbounded coords=jump,
minor tick num=4,
%x filter/.expression={
%x<=y ? nan : x
%},    
]

\addplot3[
surf,
%   contour gnuplot={number=10},
    domain=500:100,
    domain y=100:1500,
    samples=25, 
] 
{{kqd2(x,y,500)>1 || kqd2(x,y,500)<-1? -0.5 : kqd2(x,y,500)}};
%{{ x<=y ? 0 : kqd2(x,y,500)}};
%\addplot3[color=black,domain=500:200,samples y=0] ({zeta(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subsection{Plotted Equation}
Eq. \ref{eq1} is the derivative from Eq \ref{e:k} for the dialysate flow QD  which describes the mass transfer inside a dialyzer.

\begin{align}
\dfrac{b\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{d}\left(bd\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{d}+\left(k-b\right)\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{b}d-bk\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{b}\right)}{d\left(b\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{d}-\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{b}d\right)^2}
\label{eq1}
\\
K_{Diffusion} =\begin{cases} QB \frac{e^{\frac{koA}{QB}-\frac{KoA}{QD}}-1}{e^{\frac{koA}{QB}- \frac{KoA}{QD}}-\frac{QB}{QD}} 
\quad & if \frac{QB}{QD} \neq 1 \\
 \frac{KoA}{\frac{KoA}{QB}+1} 
 \quad & if \frac{QB}{QD} = 1\end{cases} \label{e:k}
\end{align}


%Failing tikz-Gnuplot script

\begin{tikzpicture}
[show background rectangle,tight background,
]
\begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth,
       height=0.8\textwidth,
    title={nummer1}, 
    xlabel=$QB$, ylabel=$QD$, zlabel=$\frac{\partial k}{\partial QD}$,
    xtick={200, 300,400, 500},
        ytick={ 500,1000,1500},
             zlabel style={yshift=-0.25cm}, 
     xlabel style={yshift=0.25cm},
          ylabel style={yshift=.25cm},
%          zmin=0, zmax=1,
                   ztick={0,0.5,1},
          x dir=reverse,
          grid=major,
%           unbounded coords=jump,
minor tick num=4,
]
\addplot3[raw gnuplot, surf] 
        gnuplot [id=surf]{
set title "3D surface from a function" 
set xlabel "QD" 
set xrange [ 500 : 200]
set ylabel "QD" 
set yrange [200 : 1500 ]
set contour
set zlabel "K" 
set samples 100, 100
set samples 100, 100
set contour
Kle(x,y,k)=((x*exp(k/y)*(x*y*exp(k/y)+(k-x)*exp(k/x)*y-x*k*exp(k/x)))/(y*(x*exp(k/y)-exp(k/x)*y)**2))
splot Kle(x,y,500)
}; \addlegendentry{$\sin(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The denominator of the function becomes zero for `b=d`. You would also help yourself and others if you tried to make clearer in the analytic discussion what the plot variables are and typeset the function more nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer only deals with the pgfplots aspect of the question. You try to plot a function that is not well-defined in its full plot domain. In more detail, the denominator of the function vanishes for `b=d`. `pgfplots` is not a computer algebra system. One way to avoid the problem is to choose the samples in such a way that these critical points get avoided.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}


\subsection*{Plotted function}
The denominator of the function
\begin{equation}
k(b,d)=\dfrac{b\,\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{d}\,\left(b\,d\,
\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{d}+\left(k-b\right)\,\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{b}\,d-b\,k\,\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{b}\right)}{d\,\left(b\,\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{d}-\mathrm{e}^\frac{k}{b}\,d\right)^2}
\end{equation}
vanishes at $b=d$. If we choose the samples such that these points are avoided,
the plot looks much better (see Figure~\ref{fig:k}).

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background,
declare function={
kqd2(\qb,\qd,\koa) =
((\qb*e^(\koa/\qd)*(\qb*\qd*exp(\koa/\qd)+(\koa-\qb)*exp(\koa/\qb)*\qd-\qb*\koa*exp(\koa/\qb)))/(\qd*(\qb*exp(\koa/\qd)-exp(\koa/\qb)*\qd)^2));
},
]
\begin{axis}[
width=0.9\textwidth,
       height=0.7\textwidth,
    title={nummer1}, 
    xlabel=$QB$, ylabel=$QD$, zlabel=$\frac{\partial k}{\partial QD}$,
    xtick={200, 300,400, 500},
        ytick={ 500,1000,1500},
             zlabel style={yshift=-0.25cm}, 
     xlabel style={yshift=0.25cm},
          ylabel style={yshift=.25cm},
%          zmin=0, zmax=1,
                   ztick={0,0.5,1},
          x dir=reverse,
          grid=major,
%           unbounded coords=jump,
minor tick num=4]

\addplot3[
surf,
%   contour gnuplot={number=10},
    domain=503:103,
    domain y=100:1500,
    samples=25, 
] 
{{kqd2(x,y,500)>1 || kqd2(x,y,500)<-1? -0.5 : kqd2(x,y,500)}};
%{{ x<=y ? 0 : kqd2(x,y,500)}};
%\addplot3[color=black,domain=500:200,samples y=0] ({zeta(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Avoiding problematic points by choosing the samples appropriately may
help.}
\label{fig:k}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: As for your updated question: I think you just did not compute the derivative correctly.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}


\subsection*{Plotted function}
The derivative of the function
\[ F(b,d,k)=\dfrac{b\,
   \left(\exp\left(\frac{k}{b}-\frac{k}{d}\right)-1\right)}{%
   \exp\left(\frac{k}{b}-\frac{k}{d}\right)-\frac{b}{d}}\]
is   
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial F(b,d,k)}{\partial d}=\begin{dcases}
\dfrac{b \,\mathrm{e}^{k/d}\, \left(d\,
k\,\mathrm{e}^{k/b}\right)-b\,
   \left(d\,
   \left(\mathrm{e}^{k/b}-\mathrm{e}^{k/d}\right)+k\,
   \mathrm{e}^{k/b}\right)}{d\,\left(d\,
   \mathrm{e}^{k/b}-b\, \mathrm{e}^{k/d}\right)^2}
   & \text{if}~b\ne d\;,\\
   \frac{k^2}{2 (d+k)^2}& \text{if}~b= d\;.
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}   
It is plotted in Figure~\ref{fig:k}.

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background,
declare function={kqd2(\b,\d,\k)=ifthenelse(\b==\d,%
\k*\k/(2*pow(\d + \k,2)),%
(\b*exp(\k/\d)*(\d*exp(\k/\b)*\k - 
       \b*(\d*(exp(\k/\b) - exp(\k/\d)) + 
          exp(\k/\b)*\k)))/(\d*pow(\d*exp(\k/\b) - \b*exp(\k/\d),2));
},
]
\begin{axis}[
width=0.9\textwidth,
       height=0.7\textwidth,
    title={nummer1}, 
    xlabel=$QB$, ylabel=$QD$, zlabel=$\frac{\partial k}{\partial QD}$,
    xtick={200, 300,400, 500},
        ytick={ 500,1000,1500},
             zlabel style={yshift=-0.25cm}, 
     xlabel style={yshift=0.25cm},
          ylabel style={yshift=.25cm},
                   ztick={0,0.5,1},
          x dir=reverse,
          grid=major,
minor tick num=4]

\addplot3[
surf,
    domain=500:100,
    domain y=100:1500,
    samples=25, 
] 
{{kqd2(x,y,500)>1 || kqd2(x,y,500)<-1? -0.5 : kqd2(x,y,500)}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Derivative $\frac{\partial F(b,d,k)}{\partial d}$.}
\label{fig:k}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thats a nice workaround, thanks. Do you now why gnuplot is not bothered by this singularity?

Comment: @94bb494nd41f I am sorry, I do not because I do not use gnu plot myself. (Another possible way would be to just define the function differently for `b==d`. I have no intuition on what this function represents, so I do not know if that's reasonable.)

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat i edited the OP, it is the derivative of the Masstransport inside a dialyzer, just FYI

Comment: @94bb494nd41f I think you just did not compute the derivative correctly, i.e. did not punch in the correct derivative to be plotted by pgfpfplots. When you compute the actual derivative, you find that it has an analytic continuation to `b=d` and is regular everywhere. Please see the update.

Comment: hey what tool did you use for the calculating the derivative? every tool used results in k^2/(k+d)^2 and not k^2/2*(k+d)^2

Comment: @94bb494nd41f I just took the expression for `b\ne d` and then took the limit `b\to d`. That's what is meant by analytic continuation. If you do it your way, you need to be careful to take into account combinatorial factors. That is, you cannot simply set `b=d` and then take the derivative. In any case, the point is that I do not think you plot the correct function, and hence he spikes.